# Click does not work in Selenium - Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have faced a critical problem in my work. I have passed 2 days but can not solve it. I have used several options but not working in automation but working in **manual processes**. I know I am wrong but can not find it.
I also use explicit and implicit wait.

I used the following code to submit a form.

`By btnSubmit = By.id("btnSubmit");`

- `driver.findElement(btnSubmit).click();`
- `driver.findElement(btnSubmit).submit();`
- `javaScript.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(btnSubmit));`

```
public Object executeScript(String script, Object... args) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        return js.executeScript(script, args);
    }
```

```
javaScript.executeScript("document.getElementById('btnSubmit').setAttribute('class','btn-small');");
```

this code added class in "btnSubmit".

But click not working. If you have time would you please give me feedback. I have attached some scenarios.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Do not worry about console error, I have checked when I do manual click on submit button, it works.

Comment: Can you share link to the website

Comment: Are you sure nothing happens? In the JS a checkbox is checked if checked (O_o), is it? Can't spot it on the screens.

Comment: @PDHide sorry I can't.

Comment: @bish when submit button clicked page load, but no page loading happen. Yes something happen, because I can add css class "btn-small".

Comment: Based on your eclipse console log, it successfully clicked the "btnSubmit". I assume that it's either there's issue with your data that's why it won't proceed or that element is not really the trigger.

Comment: @MillieAnneVolante thanks, I try to find out but still no luck. Yes console shows click but not trigger. I think data is ok, because when I click manually to interrupt automation it procced with same data. Ok thanks again.

Comment: @MillieAnneVolante thanks again, your clue help me to dig down and I solved it. Yes it is data related problem. Thanks again for your clue.